# cannot use the pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

When I finish installing pyaudio and calling it,

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

before use
[before use the pyaudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bzrz.png)

after use

[after use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6qUn.png)
[microphone was destroyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDUxT.png)

the terminal will get stuck, and my microphone cannot detect it.

The entire system also becomes extremely stuck, and I have to restart to recover. What should I do？

how to fix it ????????